# How to read CSS value of pseudo class

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

I want to read the CSS property with pseudo classes. For ex in my case `:hover` of a given element. I've used `getComputedStyle` but is not returning the desired value.

**Here's the HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   #lo {
     color: green;
   }

   #lo:hover {
     color: black;
   }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="yo" id="lo">hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's the JS:**

```
let element = document.getElementById("lo");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(element,':hover').getPropertyValue("color"));
```

It returns `rgb(0, 128, 0)` instead of `black`.

How to read the correct property value? Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: As far as I know this will not work with `hover` ~ that is a `pseudo-class` rather than a `pseudo-element`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any workaround for this? @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: You might be able to do it by reading the CSS stylesheet but I really don't know for sure.